# Print all pages including unhidden except for one page

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to print out an Excel workbook including hidden sheets, which I have accomplished with the code below. I need help with excluding sheet "A" from being printed. All sheet "A" does is fill out the other worksheet information. So it is just a waste of paper being printed.

```
Sub PrintEachPage()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CurSheet As Worksheet
    Set CurSheet = ActiveSheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible = False Then
        If LCase(ws.Name) <> "a" Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ws.PrintOut
        ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Else
        ws.PrintOut
        End If
    End If
    Next ws
    CurSheet.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Visible` is not boolean so use `If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then`

---

Eliminate sheet "a" at the first check. Then unhide the hidden ones, print them, hide them. If visible, then just print.

---

```
 Sub PrintEachPage()
        Dim ws          As Worksheet
        Dim CurSheet    As Worksheet

        Set CurSheet = ActiveSheet

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If LCase(ws.Name) <> "a" Then
                If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
                    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                    ws.PrintOut
                    ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
                Else
                    ws.PrintOut
                End If
            End If
        Next ws

        CurSheet.Activate
    End Sub
```